# Cannot validate component with empty value

Tags: validation, jsf

I've got this .xhtml file for the registration page:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password"
               value="#{registraCliente.password}"
               required="true"
               binding="#{password}"
               requiredMessage="Password obbligatoria"
               validatorMessage="Password non valida">

    <f:validateRegex pattern="(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" style="color:red" />

<h:inputSecret id="confermaPassword"
               required="true"
               value="#{registraCliente.confermaPassword}"
               requiredMessage="Devi inserire di nuovo la password">

    <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="password" value="#{password}" />
</h:inputSecret>

<h:message for="confermaPassword" style="color:red" />
```

and I want this: if the two input passwords are different, it shows me an error. But if they're the same, then the registration is allowed.
I've also added a validateRegex tag to check the "strength" of the password, but that's when I got some problems.
When I start the server and fill the form (writing the same password in both input text), it should register but it doesn't, it remains on the same xhtml page.

Eclipse's console gives me this warning:

> cannot validate component with empty value: j_id_4:confermaPassword

How it comes?

The `passwordValidator` (link in the comments below) is a bean that implements Validator, I copied it from a blog post of Balusc, who's a JSF guru I should say :D

Comment: That warning (not error!) and the failed submit are unrelated. I can explain that warning, but I can't explain the failed submit based on the information provided so far. You're not terribly clear on "it doesn't" part. You mean to say that invoke application phase isn't executed due to a validation error? If so, which one exactly? Are you making sure that you're showing and updating all faces messages in the form?

Comment: Hi @BalusC, I wasn't that clear, sorry about that...
I'll try again: without the validateRegex tag, the page runs fine and I can submit the registraton form easily.
Then, if I use that validateRegex too, I get a NullPointerException in any case , at the 39th line of the PasswordValidator: 
[link](https://github.com/enduavon/progetto_siw/blob/master/src/it/uniroma3/cikmed/beanController/PasswordValidator.java)

As you can see, I've also tried to define a regex check (now it's commented) in the PasswordValidator, in order to avoid that validateRegex tag, but that doesn't work too.